# Как определить область/край посетителя сайта?

Tags: php

На сайте нужно реализовать при оформлении заявки получать от посетителя сайта не только информацию, которую он вводит, но и также информации о его географическом положении. Как это можно реализовать, и можно ли вообще?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если PHP, то http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php

Answer (score 0):

http://htmlbook.ru/html5/geolocation